# Different behaviour between imported and harvested records in GeoNetwork 3.4.0

Tags: xml, metadata, geonetwork

I'm working on Geonetwork 3.4.0 and I have some metadata files generated with ArcGIS 10.5.

The XML files are stored into a folder that I would like to harvest, but when harvesting, it says "badFormat" and doesn't load anything.

If I import manually through "Import new records", the records are imported without issues.

I tried it with 3.4.0 and 3.4.1 versions. Please find below a link to an example record.

Is that the expected behaviour or a bug?

Please note I asked the same question on the GeoNetwork users mailing list (and just had the idea to put here today).

[1] https://gist.github.com/Bakaniko/db59ed33012313121eaf81c0e7d9ac76

Comment: How are you doing your harvest?

Comment: It was with a Local File System harvester like described [in the documentation](https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/3.4.x/en/user-guide/harvesting/harvesting-filesystem.html)